# Determination of optimum gain for neutron detection system?

Tags: radiation, electronics, neutrons, nuclear-engineering, particle-detectors

I have a Hamamtsu PMT that operates at 1500V. I've used different gains, and got different curves for each (shown in figure, x-axis is channel number, y-axis is number of counts). How does one determine the best gain to use for their detector? The dead time seems to increase with increase in gain. In the figure, gain 3 and 5.23 had about 0.02% dead time, while gain 10 had 34%, gain 21 had 60%, gain 50 had 75%. What method/analysis should be followed to determine the best gain for a detector? THanks! 
[image: AmBe Neutron Spectra]

Comment: Did you have a mono-energetic neutron source to generate these curves?  How was dead time determined?  Also one last question. The x axis is channel number but is channel number determined from neutron energy, TOF, or what?

Comment: @john I'm using a AmBe source. The dead time is determined through MAESTRO software, it specifies the real and live time, from that dead time was calculated. Y-axis is channel number from neutron energy.

Comment: My only guess is that the very high gain maybe amplifying noise such that it gets counted by detector electronics but discarded for some reason so it doesn't appear in spectrum.

Comment: Have you checked the pulses from the detector with an oscilloscope?  Notice anything with the large gain setting?

Comment: @john yes, they are very random and all over the place, with different pulse heights (with large gain). With smaller gain, they are nice clean, single pulses every 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: that sure sounds like noise to me. Are you at an University or accelerator lab?  Just curious.

Comment: @john Thanks for your input! I am at a university lab